# Infinity cycle for textView on iOS 10.2

Tags: ios, textview, infinity, layoutsubviews

I connected the library - JVFloatLabeledTextField to my project.
I started on a real device, but the problem can be reproduced on the simulator (I tried with iphone 7 plus iOS 10.2). If you enter some text in the textView, then select the text and click "Select All". The application will be in an infinity cycle, called layoutSubviews.

I tried to fix the problem and added a custom class for the textView. I redefine the intrinsicContentSize, it works, but there are other difficulties. Tell me how to fix this problem. The test project was add into my repository:
https://github.com/ed8009/textView-With-JVFloatLabeledTextView

Comment: The problem occurs when scrollEnabled = NO

Comment: I do not quite understand this code, but if I remove it, everything works fine:
if (!self.scrollEnabled && !CGSizeEqualToSize(self.bounds.size, [self intrinsicContentSize])) {
        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have identified the issue. The problem is with this part of the code.

```
if (!self.scrollEnabled && !CGSizeEqualToSize(self.bounds.size, [self intrinsicContentSize])) { 
 [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize]; 
}
```

Especially, `[self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];`

Upon calling this, the intrinsicContentSize and self.bounds.size never match. Thus, the view is laid out infinitely. The way to combat this to change this to `[self layoutIfNeeded];` This will synchronously update the layout and fix this problem. Your code should look like this.

```
if (!self.scrollEnabled && !CGSizeEqualToSize(self.bounds.size, [self intrinsicContentSize])) {
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```